# Running kibana with docker - ENV variables not set

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am trying to setup a development `elastic search` + `kibana` servers.

Elastic search server is up and running.

When I am trying to run the `kibana` image, for some reason it ignores my `env-varaibles`

This is the command i am using:

```
sudo docker run -dit --name qa-kibana --restart unless-stopped -e SERVER_PORT='5601' -e ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS='http://192.168.4.146:9200' -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.7.1
```

Then when the container is running, in the `/usr/share/config/kibana.yml` I see the default configurations and not my `env-variables`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values in `/usr/share/config/kibana.yml` are never overwritten (the file is not changed).

The environment variables are used by `/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker`, which is the default command that is fired when you start the container.